# JS function to listen to select element and change CSS style depending on the selected option?

Tags: javascript

I have a select element and a div:

```
<select>
    <option value="v_1"></option>
    <option value="v_2"></option>
    <option value="v_3"></option>
</select>
<div id="div_id"></div>
```

If the user selects option 3, I want the div to get `display:block`. If option 1 or 2 are selected, the div should get `display:none`. So if you change the selection, the div appears and disappears.

I can do this with:

```
<option onClick="document.getElementById('div_id').style.display = 'block'">
```

but I find this creates confusing and redundant code, if I have many options.

**How can I define a function that "listens" to what happens at the select element and displays or hides the div according to the selected option?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `onchange` event on a select element/tag and not an `onclick` event.

**HTML**

```
<select onchange="toggle(this)">
    <option value="">-- please choose --</option>
    <option value="v_1">1</option>
    <option value="v_2">2</option>
    <option value="v_3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="div_id">Some Data</div>
```

**JS** (by value) **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/T44cM/)**

```
function toggle(el){
    var value = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value,
        div = document.getElementById('div_id');

    if (value === 'v_1' || value === 'v_2') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (value === 'v_3') {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

**JS** (by index)

```
function toggle(el){
    var idx = el.selectedIndex,
        div = document.getElementById('div_id');

    if (idx <= 1) {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (idx >= 2) {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Can I do something like `if (option_index < 3)`? Otherwise I'll have a lot of stuff in the if-parenthesis, if there's many options.

Comment: is it the index you're trying to target or the value?

Comment: The index. Sorry for being so vague, I don't know the proper terminology.

Comment: index starts from 0 and not 1, it 3 is selected the index is actually 2 and not 3